# Adding SQL Azure Error codes that are retried

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database, enterprise-library

We're using v5.1.1212 of the NuGet package for Enterprise Library Transient Fault Handling along with EntityFramework 5 in our Net 4.5.1 application. Overall it works well for us with SQL Azure, however I would like to add a couple more SQL Azure error codes to the list that are considered retriable. Is that possible?

We see enough -1, -2 and 10054 errors from SQL Azure that I am comfortable retrying them. I realize the general guidance is not to retry the -2 errors (not sure on -1 and 10054) but the quantities we seem them in I feel it would benefit our app. Any idea how I might do this?

Comment: What about defining custom error detection strategy?

Comment: Any insights on how to do that?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680940%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx unfortunately current version of default SQL retry strategy is sealed, so it is impossible to use it as parent. Anyway, this seems to be a good variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom detection strategy. 
Alternatively, post your suggested codes to the Issue tracker on https://topaz.codeplex.com/ and someone from the project team or the community (yes, the project now [accepts community contributions](http://aka.ms/entlibopen)) will update the block.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, this turns out to be very straightforward to implement. I even discovered in the topaz source code an example of overriding the detection strategy in the obsolete SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy class. Also it turns out that 10054 is already considered transient, in looking back through my logs I only see this error when using the universal Session State provider, which does not yet use topaz.